# How to use jquery file upload with express.js?

Tags: node.js, upload, express, progress-bar

since uploading file with progress can not be done in all browser with pure js,

i want to give jquery file upload a shot，but the doc is really not good ,

so can anyone help me, or do u have any good tutorials?

Comment: I've had to highly modify it to work well with my node/express server... Don't really have any good tutorials for it, sorry. I recommend just getting it to work with its example server.js file and then modify to suit your needs.

Comment: thanx man its so hard to upload file to express! god